# Panel scrolls to first enabled control - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a heap of controls on a panel. All controls on the panel are disabled except for the last control. When I load the form with the panel it scrolls automatically to the first enabled control even when setting the vertical scroll value to 0. When setting the vertical scroll value to 0, the panel loads at the top but half a second later it scrolls to the bottom. What do I have to do to make the panel not scroll to the bottom (first enabled control)?

Comment: it might be doing that because that control is TabIndex = 0.  in which case Windows is trying to help make your app usable by scrolling the current active control into view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed Plutonix's comment. The panel does automatically scroll down to the nearest control enabled/visible with the FIRST tabindex it detects.

A method perhaps to get around this is to place a control on top (say, a radiobutton already checked) and set it's tabindex property to 0.

Comment: This fixed it... Thanks! Tab index is the last thing I would've looked at.